# How to remove the "track" on Videogular2 CuePoints running on Firefox?

Tags: angular, video, html5-video, videogular

If you access the [demo](https://videogular.github.io/videogular2-showroom/#/cue-points-player) from Videogular2 on Firefox, when the timer hits the CuePoint it shows the track with the "object" as the CuePoint info-layer on the side.

On Chrome it works just fine.

There is a way to keep the cue-points and hide the track? Maybe with CSS or something like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably is to late, but you can hide them adding this rule to the css

```
 ::cue { visibility:hidden;}
```